# How the numerical key of an array preceding with '+' sign is casted into integer type?

Tags: php, arrays, casting, integer, key

According to the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
>   type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key
>     "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not
>     be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

As per about quotes I wrote following code. In below code the key +8 is getting cast to the integer type. How this is possible as the above rule says it should not happen?

```
<?php
$array = array(
    +8    => "a"
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
array(1) {
  [8]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

Comment: +8 cast to integer, if you quote it '+8' or "+8", it will cast to string

Comment: The text is talking about how _strings_ are cast when being array keys. `+8` (without quotes) isn't a string, it's simply an integer. Demo: https://3v4l.org/mRWi6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `+8` is an integer literal and, as such, the + sign is implicit and it makes no difference to add it or not:

```
var_dump(+8, 8);
```

> ```
> int(8)
> int(8)
> ```

Nothing in the docs state that PHP will cast integers to strings. I think you just misread this sentence (emphasis mine):

> **Strings** containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is preceded by a + sign

```
$array = array(
    7 => 'a',
    +8 => 'b',
    '+9' => 'c',
);
var_dump(array_keys($array));
```

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   int(7)
>   [1]=>
>   int(8)
>   [2]=>
>   string(2) "+9"
> }
> ```